# Inject specific Doctrine entity in Symfony2 service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I'm currently using an entity with a specific ID in a service.  To make this work using dependency injection, I am injecting the entity repository and a specific ID.  For example:

```
public function __construct($myRepo, $myId) {
    $this->myEntity = $myRepo->find($myId);
}
```

Is there a way to directly inject this specific entity without passing in the repository?  For example, the ideal method would be:

```
public function __construct($myEntity) {
    $this->myEntity = $myEntity;
}
```

I can't figure out how to define the services that are needed to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wouter makes a good point about services being stateless.  However, you can use the DI factory capability to accomplish your goal:

```
specific_entity:
    class:  SomeEntity # Not used but you still need something here
    factory_service:  specific_entity_repository
    factory_method:   find
    arguments:  
        - 42
```

This will call the find method on your repository with an argument of 42.  The returned entity will then be injected.  I'm assuming you already know how to setup a repository as a service.

Answer (score 4):

Services should be stateless. Saving a user with a specific id in a service makes them statefull.

Instead of passing the entity in the constructor and saving it in a property, the entity should be passed to the method that is called. E.g. instead of a mailer with the `to` address passed into the constructor, it should be passed to the `mailer#mail()` method.

Comment: Very nice, it makes sense to keep them stateless.  However, I am unsure how to inject the specific entity that I need into the method that uses it, since it is a protected method.

Comment: well, the method is called from somewhere... Pass it to that place

Comment: I guess I'm not following you.  The method is called from within the service, so in order to pass it to that method, the service needs to know about it.